# The best practices of chrome extension logging or How to implement logging in extension for chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, logging, google-chrome-extension

I need to implement logging in the extension for chrome.
Remote logging (for example using jsnlog) is not suitable. Logging occurs on different pages

I see two solutions to this problem but I don't like them, each of them has its drawbacks. Both of these solutions are based on saving of logs in storage in the form of a circular singly linked list. Each message is stored as a separate entry in the storage with the key ("mylogmess#..") also has a pointer to the next free key ("mylogmess#.. + 1") to add new message which is also located in the storage ("mypointer).

The storage structure is as follows:

```
{

  "mypointer": 5,

  "mylogmess#0": "H",

  "mylogmess#1": "e",

  "mylogmess#2": "l",

  "mylogmess#3": "l",

  "mylogmess#4": "o",

}
```

The first algorithm is simple: read the pointer, create the log messages with a key from the pointer, incrementing a pointer, write to store updated pointer and a new message.

As a result, the complexity of the operation logging a single message is the following: 1 read from the store (get pointer) 1 write in the store (set updated pointer + message).

The disadvantage of this method is that not all messages are saving, because the read and write access to the storage occur asynchronously, the pointer has no time to update and as a result messages are overwritten.

The second algorithm is based on sending messages to background page. In this case, the pointer will be read only once (at startup extension), and then it will only recorded in the chrome storage. This method is not pleasant to me from an architectural point of view.

What method of logging you can recommend?

Comment: It'd be helpful if you add to the question why the latter method of using a background page is not pleasant from an architectural point of view.

Comment: not clear whats the difference between both. both use chrome storage. look instead at indexedDb

Comment: @ZigMandel indexedDb is unique for different tabs, and I need a single shared storage

Comment: no. you use it from background of course :) the other storages is overkill to use linked lists like that.

Comment: I want to move all logging logic into a separate class in a separate file. I use storage because I prefer the first variant of implementation (without background page)

Comment: @wOxxOm I'm not satisfied with the background page as an intermediary between the sender and the recipient of the log messages

Comment: And why are you not satisfied? This is the basic technique used in Chrome extensions.

Comment: @wOxxOm I want to communicate directly with the Logger from all the pages and not put any extra logic for saving in storage on the background page. If work through the background page, then each log message essentially turns into chrome.runtime.sendMessage({msg: 'send log', data: logMessage }, null) and on the background page, call logger.log(logMessage) instead of immediately call logger.log(...).